# Rails Grape API 'id is invalid' in request that requires no id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, grape-api, doorkeeper

I have a Grape API protected by Doorkeeper and I have a bunch of methods which work perfectly. However, there's one method that behaves weirdly.
It is a GET request that requires no parameters and running it throws the following error:

> Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors at /v1/discount_cards/all.json
>
> id is invalid

My method looks like this:

```
desc 'Get all the cards of current customer'
params {}
get 'all' do
  current_customer.discount_cards.to_json(include:
  {
    barcode: {
      include: :barcode_type
    }
  })
end
```

The logs say that the error happens at line 17 of the `logger.rb` file, which looks like this:

```
module API
  class Logger
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      payload = {
        remote_addr: env['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        request_method: env['REQUEST_METHOD'],
        request_path: env['PATH_INFO'],
        request_query: env['QUERY_STRING'],
        x_organization: env['HTTP_X_ORGANIZATION']
      }

      ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument 'grape.request', payload do
        @app.call(env).tap do |response| # <-- logs say the error is here
          payload[:params] = env['api.endpoint'].params.to_hash
          payload[:params].delete('route_info')
          payload[:params].delete('format')
          payload[:response_status] = response[0]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My main `base.rb` class looks like this:

```
module API
  class Dispatch < Grape::API
    mount API::V1::Base
  end

  Base = Rack::Builder.new do
    use API::Logger
    run API::Dispatch
  end
end
```

---

I really cannot understand what `id` it is talking about, and, moreover, all the other api methods work absolutely fine (post, get, put, delete).

Could you help me with resolving that issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? 
Even I'm facing the same issue and I'm not able to understand what it is trying to convey from the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue recently too, and it turned out to be an issue of code order for me.  I found the answer [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/32665311-error-id-is-invalid-on-get-route).

> Grape evaluates routes in order, so with two routes, /:id and /nearby_missions, it matches /:id first, making id=nearby_missions. Then it tries to coerce nearby_missions into an Integer which fails, and you get the missing id error.
>
> You could "fix" this by adding requirements: /\d*/ to the first route (didn't test), but you're probably just better off ordering them in the order you want them to be evaluated, which is what you did.

There's not enough info in your question for me to be sure that this is also your problem, but it could well be!

Comment: The quote you have mentioned is no where mentioned in that source link https://app.bountysource.com/issues/32665311-error-id-is-invalid-on-get-route

Comment: @sofs1 check here: https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/issues/1352 (linked in the bountysource link)